# How to provide comparison and assignment operators for sorting procedure

Tags: c#, sorting, assignment-operator, comparison-operators

I have to arrays with this structure

```
internal sealed class Task
{
    ...
    public String Id { get; private set; }
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public UInt32 Time { get; private set; }
}
...
    private List<Task> _tasks;
    private List<Boolean[]> _tasksAllowedProcessingUnits;
```

This arrays have one-to-one correspondence. I need to sort array `_tasks` but while swapping elements in array `_tasks` i need elements in `_tasksAllowedProcessingUnits` to be swapped as well. So, one-to-one correspondence must be preserved.

For some performance reasons i don't want to put all task related data in a struct to store it in a single array.

Comment: Why are you not using `KeyValuePair` to store these mappings?

Comment: I don't understand, why would you need assignment for sorting? Also in c# you usually don't implement operators but relevant interfaces or by providing comparer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything pre-done. Clearly there are various solutions

A) You find the source of an implementation of QuickSort and you do the Sort + Sort "manually" with that code

B) You create an overobject that references `Task` and `Boolean[]` and sort a collection of that.

```
List<Tuple<Task, Boolean[]>> lst = Enumerable.Range(0, _tasks.Count).Select(ix => Tuple.Create(_tasks[ix], _tasksAllowedProcessingUnits[ix])).ToList();
lst.Sort((p, q) => p.Item1.CompareTo(q.Item1));

for (int i = 0; i < _tasks.Count; i++) {
    _tasks[i] = lst[i].Item1;
    _tasksAllowedProcessingUnits[i] = lst[i].Item2
}
```

(note that the .NET `Task` object isn't comparable, so I hope you have a specialized comparer)